# Wide and deep neural network - Why is the loss fluctuating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a wide and deep neural network (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) with my own dataset.
My dataset features are numeric values. It has many columns (280) and it is balanced by category. It's a binary classification problem with two labels: 0 and 1. All the code is the same as wide_deep.py (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep.py), with a few changes because of the dataset:

```
_CSV_COLUMNS = [ names of my columns... ]


_NUM_EXAMPLES = {
    'train': 40000,
    'validation': 10000,
}

...

def build_model_columns():
  """Builds a set of wide and deep feature columns."""

  columns = []

  for a in range(0, len(_CSV_COLUMNS)):
    _CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS.append([0.0])
    if (_CSV_COLUMNS[a] != "category"):
      columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(_CSV_COLUMNS[a]))

  wide_columns = columns
  deep_columns = columns

  return wide_columns, deep_columns

...


def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle, batch_size):
  """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""
  assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), (
      '%s not found.' % data_file)

  def parse_csv(value):
    print('Parsing', data_file)
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=_CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(_CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    labels = features.pop('category')
    return features, tf.equal(labels, 0)

  # Extract lines from input files using the Dataset API.
  dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)


 ....

 results = model.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(
    FLAGS.test_data, 1, False, FLAGS.batch_size))
```

The problem is that the loss decreases just a little at first and then it starts fluctuating.

I've tried:

- Increasing the batch size
- Trying AdamOptimizer
- Normalizing the values in my dataset ([-1,1])
- Decreasing the learning rate, like this:

  ```
  return tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
      model_dir=model_dir,
      linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
      dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
      dnn_hidden_units=hidden_units,
      dnn_optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.000001),
      config=run_config)
  ```

it doesn't matter how low the learning rate is, the loss won't go down.

The output looks like this:

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 64.00549, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 41.65817, step = 101 (10.582 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 35.131912, step = 201 (8.954 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 41.854298, step = 301 (8.012 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 24.876358, step = 401 (7.573 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 44.788383, step = 501 (9.059 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 33.58178, step = 601 (7.904 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 35.278023, step = 701 (7.751 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 28.880415, step = 801 (7.787 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 33.041504, step = 901 (8.178 sec)
...
```

It will never be as high as 64 again, but it fluctuates and it won't go lower than 24. It seems to be learning something, because the accuracy is 0.81-0.82 (it won't get any better than that, either)
What does it mean? Could my dataset have problems? Could it mean that the problem can't be solved?

Comment: What it's the biggest batch size have you used?

Comment: 500 is the biggest batch size I've tried

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with my own dnn although I do not seem to find a solution

Comment: @polmonroig I think you could try using your entire dataset as your batch size - then it should stop fluctuating. If your entire dataset is way too big for that and you run out of memory, you could try using a smaller dataset, maybe a subset of your current dataset, let's say 1000 samples, and then set batch size to 1000. The loss should go down then. I know you want to use your entire dataset, but only for a sanity check.

Comment: @polmonroig Also sometimes loss fluctuates a lot when your network is way too big (and you're using mini batches), although the general tendency should be to go down.

Comment: Okay thanks you!! I tried it with mini batches of 1000  instances and now it stop fluctuating.  Although now I need to figure out how to reduce the loss but thats another problem ;) @Kuranes